# Retrive data from Firebase and output in a textview

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, textview

I need some help with my android Project. I try to make an Android forum ("student edition") but my lack of knowledge catch up with me.
I have the fallowing Firebase database structure:
[image]

My Forum.class looks like this:

```
Button post_btn,fetch;
EditText message;
DatabaseReference forum1, comments;
TextView  post_update;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_forum);

    post_btn = findViewById(R.id.post_btn);
    message = findViewById(R.id.comment_area);
    fetch=findViewById(R.id.btnFetch);
    post_update=findViewById(R.id.tvValue);
    final String post_title = "Student " + Session.LiveSession.user.getFn() + " " + Session.LiveSession.user.getSn() + " says: ";


    forum1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("_forum1_");

    post_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          ;
            Message comment = new Message( post_title,message.getText().toString());
            forum1.child(forum1.push().getKey()).setValue(comment);



        }
    });


    fetch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            forum1.child("_forum1_").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    post_update.setText(value);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
        }
    });

  }//end of onCreate
} //end of Class
```

pst_btn is working and when a student is posting, I push the data from "message" alongside with "post_title"(witch is constructed according to user) into the Firebase.

I will like some help with my "fetch" method. I try to make a button that extracts the data from firebase into a "textview"

My question is: How can I place following inside my textview: "post_title"+"message"??

Example of desired output:

Student Willy Weiss says: ssss

Student Willy Weiss says: qqq

Student Willy Weiss says: dfsfsfsf

Can some one help me with this? I have zero knowledge about Arrays or HashMaps, so if you recommend something like this , please leave some example code so I can learn/figure out what you recommend.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 fetch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                forum1.child("_forum1_").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                      for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        String msg = ds.child("message").getValue(String.class);
                        String value = ds.child("post_title").getValue(String.class);
                        post_update.setText(value +" "+ msg);
                     }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Iterate using `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` and then retrieve both the message and post_title and pass them to `setText()`

Comment: Works but I receive only the last entry from the data base, not all. how can I extend this method in order to grab all the data?

Comment: Create an ArrayList and keep adding the data. You can then use the ArrayList to populate fields. The for loop in your code will keep updating until the last value is reached.

Comment: if you want all then just use a recyclerview

Comment: Just for curious, `forum1` already reference to  *_forum1_*, then how `forum1.child("_forum1_")` works?

Comment: I`m a contemplate beginner in Java/Android with no teacher in class. I was just trying to make thing works, one way or another.